# Need help understanding notation

Tags: notation

The textual description of the space $G$ is as follows:

$G(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is the Banach space composed of the distributions $f$ which can be written as $f = \mathrm{div}(g)$, where $\mathrm{div}:Y\rightarrow X$.

Later on in the paper, a discrete version of $G$ is given with the following definition:

$G_d = \{ v \in X / \exists g \in Y \;\; \mathrm{s.t.} \;\; v = \mathrm{div}(g) \}$

Am I correct in reading the $/$ symbol as "such that"? I am only familiar with $/$ to indicate a quotient space.Or is the above a quotient space that I am missing?

Comment: I think that must be it. I've seen this, but only in old texts.

Comment: Maybe it’s a typo for a vertical bar? When I was a boy (he says, his voice cracking), the vertical bar commonly meant “such that” when it appeared between braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost certainly the case that the / should be read as "such that" as you expect.